# Connection to a private k8s cluster: failed to find any PEM

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes cluster which is running in a private cloud. I want to run some commands from another VM but I receive this:

```
[root@runner-tmp ~]# kubectl get pods --kubeconfig local-cluster.yaml
error: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input
```

My local-cluster.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://x.x.x.x:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    namespace: FSM
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

Do you have any idea where should I specify this PEM certificate and how can I generate it?

Comment: If your `-data:` fields do not start with `LS0tLS1` then they are encoded incorrectly. They should also not contain any newline characters, it should be all one big long string. The correct fix is to use the `kubectl config set-credentials` command with the correct flags in order to recreate that `kubernetes-admin` user, versus editing the file by hand and risking having to ask a S.F. question

Comment: separately, as far as I know kubernetes names, of which your `namespace: FSM` one, must be lowercase and dns compatible, so I would be stunned if you have an all capital Namespace in your cluster

Answer (score 1):

Message `error: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input` appears when you copy output of `kubectl config view` to remote VM.

So instead of copying output of `kubectl config view` to your remote VM you should provide entire `config` file that is usually present in `$HOME/.kube/config`.

You can do it by running `scp root@<control-plane-host>:/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf .` and then providing this file as `--kubeconfig`, for example:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig ./admin.conf get nodes
```